# Why is the order reversed in the conjugate symmetry axiom for the inner-product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The conjugate symmetry axiom for the inner product is as follows:

$$\overline{\langle x,y\rangle } = \langle y,x\rangle$$

It is my understanding that the conjugate is there so that the norm of a vector can be defined, but I do not understand why it is also necessary to swap the order, why not define it like this:

$$\overline{\langle x,y\rangle } = \langle x,y\rangle$$

I can understand why that swapping the order may be useful if both $x$, and $y$ are real, since this allows the inner product to behave like the dot product, but I do not understand how complex values of $x$ and $y$ fit into this.

For example, is the following true when both $x$ and $y$ are complex?

$$\langle x,y\rangle  =\langle y,x\rangle$$

Comment: If $\overline{\langle x, y \rangle} = \langle x, y \rangle$, then $\langle x, y \rangle$ would always be real. That would make sense if the vectors in question are in a real vector space. But in a complex vector space this will make it impossible to satisfy the linearity conditions on the inner product.

Comment: @DavidGao does the order swap exist only to allow  $$ \langle y,x\rangle $$ to produce complex values?  I am confused as it was first introduced to me that $$\langle x,y\rangle  = \langle y,x\rangle$$ for real numbers

Comment: In a sense. You could have required $\langle x, y \rangle = \langle y, x \rangle$, but with complex values, that would not produce a norm. (Just think of the usual bilinear dot product $\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_i x_iy_i$ - it would not satisfy $\langle x, x \rangle$ being positive, or even real, for that matter.) If, as I mentioned, you instead require $\overline{\langle x, y \rangle} = \langle x, y \rangle$, that would be equivalent to the inner product always taking real values, making it impossible to be complex-linear.

Comment: So, the only way to both produce a norm and ensure some form of complex-linearity is to require $\overline{\langle x, y \rangle} = \langle y, x \rangle$. This means the inner product can be required to be complex-linear in one variable and conjugate-linear in other, and also required to produce a norm $\|x\| = \langle x, x \rangle^{1/2}$.